# Swagger and formatting text

Tags: c#, swagger, swagger-ui

I have the following property with XML comments:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <example>
    /// [
    ///     {
    ///         "value": 1,
    ///         "text": "Driver John Smith"
    ///     }
    /// ]
    /// </example>
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "drivers")]
    public List<Pair<int, string>> Drivers { get; set; }
```

Swagger is being generated it as :

```
"drivers": "[\r\n    {\r\n        \"value\": 1,\r\n        \"text\": \"Driver John Smith\"\r\n    }\r\n]",
```

Is it possible to use formatting for it?

Comment: What kind of formatting? What result do you expect to get?

Comment: I expect as wrote in `<example>` part

Comment: Do you use Swashbuckle or Swagger-Net?

Comment: @JessedeWit but I need to correct show to HTML page, not to console

Comment: @Helen Swashbuckle

Answer (score 0):

Check out this documentation for Swagger: http://wmpratt.com/swagger-and-asp-net-web-api-part-1/

You shouldn't have to explicitly create the object in the XML comment for it to be displayed in Swagger, that is generated from the class definition.
(see the 'Universe' class in the Superhero example in the link above).

You could then use the XML Comments on the classes to get some documentation in swagger around the Driver property

Comment: yes, but for generic classes (like in my case or `Tuple<>` classes) I can't set class definition